# How to update a field using trigger with data from other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a field named `valor` which will be the result of `quantidade` multiplied by `preco`.

To do this I think I should use a trigger so when a row from the table(cart_produtos) is done the field `valor` is updated.

So far I managed to do this:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER valor_update AFTER INSERT
ON cart_produtos FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cart_produtos(valor) VALUES(quantidade*);
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

My problem is that the field `preco` is on another table(produtos). I think I should use `JOIN` but I'm not sure how to get to the field value with that.

Database diagram:
[image: Database]

Comment: In general, triggers in MySQL cannot modify the table which cause them to fire.  I also don't know what you plan to do with the `preco` column.  At first glance, I was thinking that maybe you want a computed column.

Comment: No. the `preco` column as a INT value. I want to know that value so I can multiply it by the field `quantidade` so I know the total value and then UPDATE the column valor with the result from `preco`*`quantidade`. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Can't update table 'cart_produtos' in stored function/trigger because it is main table where are you apply trigger.
try use another table then it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should make a seperate table and use it to report the value.